# Mysql error: Warning: #1265 Data truncated for column 'empatt_date' at row 1

Tags: mysql, database, date

I am trying to save a Shamsi date using Jalili datepicker.
It insert correctly all the dates without (29, 30 and 31).
 but mysql gives me the following error:

> Warning: #1265 Data truncated for column 'att_date' at row 1

The date Format I am using is : (1398-02-29 , 1398/02/29)

Comment: What you are showing is not a date format. That are two dates in different formats

Comment: What is the data type of `att_date` ?

Comment: Yes I know. It is different  formats I tried but none of them  worked. And the att_date type is only "date".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your date format is not MySQL standard format. You need to change the sql mode as
`ALLOW_INVALID_DATES`. 
So it will check only that the month is in the range from 1 to 12 and the day is in the range from 1 to 31.

Adding the link of MySQL document

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_allow_invalid_dates

Comment: You can up vote the answer. So that it will be useful for others.

Answer (score 1):

Beside @james solution it's not a best practice to save date in Hijri in database as it lower the portability and compatibility of the application. Its best to save all dates in Gregorian and use some converter library to change it to whatever you need.